# Is it possible to recreate `schema.graphql` file from a schema uploaded to Apollo Engine?

Tags: graphql, apollo

After having [pushed](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-servicepush) a schema to Apollo Engine, is it possible to recreate the `schema.graphql` that was used to push the schema in the first place?

It seems that the best I can get is a JSON version of the schema with obtained with [`apollo client:download-schema`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientdownload-schema-output).

Comment: Apollo article explaining all three graphql representation formats:
https://blog.apollographql.com/three-ways-to-represent-your-graphql-schema-a41f4175100d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn any schema introspection result into SDL using the core library:

```
const { buildClientSchema, printSchema } = require('graphql')
const introspectionResult = require('./schema.json')

const schema = buildClientSchema(introspectionResult)
const sdl = printSchema(schema)
```